# How do I make a transparent background clickable?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, click, transparent

I am trying to make a transparent paint overlay for annotating the computer screen in c++.  I am at the point where I have a transparent window, but the problem is that the mouse clicks pass through the window to the windows below it.  This is how my window is created:

```
hwnd = CreateWindow (szAppName, // window class name
    0,// window caption
    WS_POPUP,//WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,// window style
    CW_USEDEFAULT,// initial x position
    CW_USEDEFAULT,// initial y position
    1920,// initial x size
    1080,// initial y size
    NULL,// parent window handle
    NULL,// window menu handle
    hInstance, // program instance handle
    NULL);// creation parameters

SetWindowPos(hwnd,HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0,  SWP_NOSIZE);
ShowWindow (hwnd, iCmdShow) ;

SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, RGB(255,255,255), 255, LWA_COLORKEY);

UpdateWindow (hwnd) ;
```

When I don't have the portions that set the window alpha, I have a working paint program with a white background.  When I set the alpha, I have a transparent window that passes all clicks.

My question is this:  How do I prevent clicks from passing through transparent windows?  I've looked into it, but all I can find is people trying to make clicks PASS-THROUGH, which is a problem I certainly don't have.

Comment: I would be correct to assume that your window procedure is looking for the click message, right?

Comment: Yes, this it is a fully functioning Paint program when alpha isn't manipulated.

Comment: How about other mouse messages?  Do you get a `WM_CAPTURECHANGED`?  Have you called `SetCapture` manually?

Comment: Also - does your window procedure respond to `WM_NCHITTEST`?